# Display auto suggest properties while coding in flash builder 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, adobe, flash-builder, flexbuilder

I have installed Flash builder 4.0 standard version.When i am writing code in adobe flex, auto suggest properties is not displaying when enter ctrl+space bar or by defautt. I have try to change setting sin preference also but it does not work.
I think there is some libraries are missing while installing. Could you please share the plugins which is missed or any other way can do this.

Regards,
Ravi

Comment: I suggest you check your shortcuts setup, it may be missing for some strange reasons

Comment: @Adrian :- i have checked all shortcut keys and it has same option like the default. There is not changes in default settings.

Comment: try and reinstall FlashBuilder. This should work...! Do you have any other tools whuci may "steal" the key combination?